# How to run a Javascript code on closing the opened window?

Tags: javascript

I want to do something when I close the opened window (let's say just print hello world on console).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
         content="IE=edge">
        <title>window</title>
        <meta name="viewport" 
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="openwindow()">Show Window</button>


        <script>
            function openwindow(){
                window.open("https://www.google.com",'newwindow',
                'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,
                resizable=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have a button. When I click this button it opens another window and opens [Google](https://www.google.com) in it.

So when I close this new window I want to run some code without opening further dialog box. How can I achieve it?

Comment: so you want to wait for that new window to close? save the return value from window.open in a variable, add a close event handler to this new window which does what you want when the use closes the opened window ... [window.open documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) ... and ... [addEventListener documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The popup window does not have any close event that you can listen to but there is a closed property that is `true` when window gets closed. You can detect that event with the help of starting a timer and checking the closed property of the child window every second and clear the timer when the window gets closed. Something like this:

```
var windowPopup = window.open("https://www.google.com",'newwindow',
                'scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800'); 
var timer = setInterval(function() { 
    if(windowPopup.closed) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        alert('closed');
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: @RafaelBerro yes this will work. I also use the same code for that requirement

Comment: i don't why but above code says Cannot read property 'closed' of null when i try to run.

Comment: @sagarlimbu In that case you need to debug your code. The null may be from some silly or unknown mistake.

Comment: I can't still think how is that possible.. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit copy paste the code into the browser console. Press enter. Then close the popup. You will get the alert message.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal Yeah I tested.. but how threads works in browser is what I'm not getting.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand you correctlly, but I think you can easily use 'onbeforeunload()' event.

```
<body onbeforeunload="myFunction()">
</body>

function myFunction() {
    localStorage.setItem("dataSet", 'dataSet');
}
```

you can check the webStorage to see that it write the variable before the page is closed.

does that helps?